# Sampler object not changing texture filter

Tags: opengl, c

I am currently binding a sampler object to a texture (GL_TEXTURE12 to be specific) with

`glBindSampler(12, sampler);`

and the initial settings are very visible compared to the textures own settings. But when I change the samplers parameters with

`glSamplerParameteri(sampler, GL_TEXTURE_***_FILTER, filter);`

the texture filters just the same as it did before with no apparent change from any perspective.

I have tried re-binding the texture to the sampler again after the parameter change but I'm pretty sure this isn't required.

What changes can I make to get this working?

Comment: could you post your code

Comment: I already found that the problem is setting the mipmap parameters on the texture causes this problem.